# Javac: invalid source release: 1.7

Tags: eclipse, maven, jdk1.7

When building war file using JDK 1.7, I am getting following error.
Javac: invalid source release: 1.7
Usage: javac  
Use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: Sounds like you are using something that requires java 1.8. Hard to tell for sure given how little information you've share.

Comment: Yes, build is working working with jdk1.8